# How to make automatic completing the word

Tags: excel, vba

My Friends,
I have two sheets (Sheet1 & Sheet2). in sheet2, Column B all the staff names,
and in the sheet1 there is a form to complete, in Cell C3 of it the name of staff is required to be written. what  I want to do is "when I write the initial letters of the employee name, I want Excel to give me option names based on Sheet2, Column B. like when we write in Google anything, Google give options.

thanks in Advance for your help.

Comment: You can define one list "StafList" and with cell("C3") :Data -> Validation -> Allow -> List
in the source box type:
=StafList.
otherwise you need vba, use intersect in range C:C,.....

Comment: thanks for this idea

Answer (score 0):

another idea is use VBA, I've updated the [byundt's](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=244)  code.
It's not possible to show immediately the autofill, but you can type some characters and when you play enter the code check the list and if is one match, autofill the data, otherwise ask user if validate the missing name and add it to the list o delete the last value entered.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cel As Range, match1 As Range, match2 As Range, rg As Range, targ As Range
    Set targ = Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) 'Watch the cells in column C
    Set sh = Worksheets("registry") 'the sheet2 where you have the list of names

    Set rg = sh.Range("A2", "A" & sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)
    If targ Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo errhandler

    For Each cel In targ
        If Not IsError(cel) Then
            If cel <> "" And cel <> " " And Right(cel, 1) <> Chr(10) Then
                Set match1 = Nothing
                Set match1 = rg.Find(cel & "*", lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
                If Not match1 Is Nothing Then
                    Set match2 = rg.FindNext(after:=match1)
                    If match2.Address = match1.Address Then
                        cel = match1
                    Else
                        cel.Activate
                        Application.SendKeys ("{F2}")
                    End If
                Else 'No matches found. The value will be added of the end of range list
                    msg = "The value """ & Target & """ is not in list, " & vbCrLf & "do you whant to add this item??"
                    response = MsgBox(msg, 4, "Update list")
                    If response = 6 Then
                        sh.Range("A" & sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1) = Target
                    Else
                        Range(Target.Address) = ""
                    End If

                End If
            Else
                If cel <> "" And Right(cel, 1) = Chr(10) Then cel = Left(cel, Len(cel) - 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next cel

errhandler:     Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: there is still problem when pressing enter, it direct me to the code "Set sh = Worksheets("registry") 'the sheet2 where you have the list of names"

Comment: then?!?!? your 2th sheets is named "registry" ?!?!?!?

Comment: change Set sh = Worksheets("registry")  to Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet2 ")